# VBA + Pivot: Run script when filter changed, but before pivot initiates refresh

Tags: vba

I am trying to figure out how to have a macro run anytime a filter/slicer is changed but also have it run before the pivot table refreshes/recalculates. I figured out a work around to this, but if there is a way to trigger a macro once a pivot table update is REQUESTED, I could write a much simpler code. I am aware there is an event that can be used after the pivot table is done refreshing, but that is not what I am looking for.

I have tried the following, which the first option below seems like it should work, but none of them worked for me and won't trigger at all during a pivot table refresh.

- PivotTableBeforeAllocateChanges
- PivotTableBeforeCommitChanges
- PivotTableBeforeDiscardChanges

And yes, I did have these within the sheets code and not inside a module. I even used the sample code from Microsoft for each of these and they still didn't trigger during a pivot refresh.

-Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a workaround, instead of handling the deletion of the formula before the pivot update runs, I just kept track of the old positioning on a reference sheet and had all the work done after the pivot update. Not as clean a work around as I would like, but it seems there is no way to intercept the process immediately after a pivot refresh is requested.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

CalcCol = Sheets("References").Range("B1")
Top = Sheets("References").Range("B2")
Bottom = Sheets("References").Range("B3")

'clearing formula column, if new columns are added, splitting the top and bottom, deletes the top portion and bottom portion
If Range(Top).End(xlDown).Address = Bottom Then
    Range(Top, Bottom).Clear
Else
    Range(Top, Range(Top).End(xlDown).Address).Clear
    If Range("A15").End(xlDown).Row < Range(Bottom).Row And Range("A15").End(xlDown) = "Grand Total" Then
        Range(Bottom, Cells(Range("A15").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row, Range(Bottom).Column)).Clear
    End If
End If

'enter formula into column immediately after the end of the pivot
Top = Range("A15").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).End(xlUp).Address
Range(Top) = "CalcCol"
Bottom = Cells(Range("A15").End(xlDown).Row, Range(Top).Column).Address

Sheets("References").Range("B1") = Range(Top).Column
Sheets("References").Range("B2") = Top
Sheets("References").Range("B3") = Bottom

Range(Range(Top).Offset(1, 0).Address) = "=ifna(Vlookup(A2,Amt!A:C,3,false),0)"
Range(Range(Top).Offset(1, 0).Address).Copy
Range(Range(Top).Offset(1, 0).Address, Range(Bottom).Address).PasteSpecial
    
End Sub
```